# Can you recommend some small plants for my new office?

Tags: plant-recommendations, office-gardening

I am basically setting up a new office and I believe placing some plants will smoothen the work there and help get rid off boredom.

Can you guys suggest some plants or setups that could make my office lively? Any common or useful tips would be warmly welcomed.

Office information:

1. The office is at Kerala, India mild moderate climate and facing east.
2. It got large windows and doors made of glass and sunlight is plenty available through out the day.
3. It is windy there most of the time and gets enough air throughout the day.

I'm looking for small plants that could be placed on desks and windows.

Comment: If you're asking what plants would be best, more info required - need to know how much natural daylight and/or sunlight the area gets, how much space there is for plants (on desks, floor, windowsills, whatever), whether the heating goes off at weekends, etc.

Comment: First, look for the other questions about [plants in offices](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=office) on this site. Second, we need a description of the office to be able to recommend plants: where is it in the world, what temperatures will you be keeping it at, amount of natural and artificial lighting, do you use climate control and so on

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra information. Are you looking for large plants (whose pots would be on the floor) or small plants (on desks or windowsills) or both?

Comment: I'm looking for small plants as you said that could be placed on desks or window stills. Thank  you Niall

Comment: The real question is what plants are available for purchase in your area? It won't help you if we recommend plants that you cannot get.

Comment: Okay.Thank you.I used to like Plants like lucky bamboo and all that we used to have at home.Any variant of that or similar would be helpful.I would Try the plants that will be available here.It would be fine if it is not available here.

Answer (score 5):

I have African Violets and Phalaenopsis orchids currently blooming in my south facing office window.  They prefer a more diffused light, however, so unless it is cloudy I keep the blinds somewhat closed - up to 75% closed. Since I work in the greater Seattle area, however, most of the time I don't have to worry about them getting too much sun.  ;-)

Other plants to consider for an office environment, depending on available light levels, might be something in the philodendron or pothos families. I've seen some nice specimens indoors thriving on fluorescent lighting alone.  A nice choice for an indoor hanging plant is the "Spider Plant (chlorophytum)."  If your office workers do not all have green thumbs, there are indoor plants that are considered very sturdy and even almost "fail proof" for most indoor garden areas, for example "Peace Lily (spathyphyllum)" and various variegated aloes, or the ever-popular "Cast Iron Plant (apidistra)" or "Mother in Law's Tongue (Sansevieria)."

Answer (score 3):

Given that half a day's sun will be available, and that you need easy care, small growing plants which don't droop and trail, I'd recommend the following, in order of preference for your situation:

1. Sansevieria hahnii (not to be confused with S. trifasciata laurentii) and Sansevieria golden hahnii. Easy care, tolerates dryness if you forget to water, doesn't get large, remains neat and tidy, doesn't mind shade nor a bit of sun.
2. Peperomia caperata and Peperomia hederaefolia - neat growers, but do not appreciate direct sunlight for any length of time, particularly in summer.
3. Iresine herbstii and Iresine aureoreticulata - needs as much sunlight as possible, but not very hot sun for any length of time.

Whether you can get any of these where you are, I don't know.